# Is it possible to use Access Tokens to login & push images to Docker Hub from Travis CI?

Tags: docker, github, travis-ci, dockerhub

This is my .travis.yml

```
    sudo: required
services:
    - docker
....
....
    # login to docker
    - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_ID" --password--stdin
    - docker push <username>/<image-name>
```

Instead of using my Docker Hub password, I generated an Access Token at https://hub.docker.com/settings/security and set then up in Travis CI like so.

[Travis CI Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZSRB.png)

However, I get the following output in my build.

```
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is possible. Docker just re-uses the "password" mechanics for the access token, which seems misleading and inconsistent with similar types of tools.

From the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/access-tokens/):

> At the password prompt, enter the personal access token.

For Travis CI specifically, specify your username via the `DOCKER_USERNAME` environment variable and your access token via the `DOCKER_PASSWORD` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I haven't had time to revisit this project. But I will be sure to look at this.